# How to make background color in viewForHeaderInSection the same as one in titleForHeaderInSection?

Tags: iphone

I want to highlight one of the titles in grouped section, just like the Calendar application. I am trying to use UILabel as the return view in viewForHeaderInSection. But I am not sure what color is in the default heder. Does anyone know? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you use titleForHeaderInSection: instead if you want it to look like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this one myself -- rather a late response, but in case somebody else runs across it, this worked for me:

> [label setBackgroundColor:[tableView backgroundColor]];

where, of course, label is the UILabel * that you're using for your header view. Rather than hardcoding a color, just use whatever background color the table view itself is using.

Answer (score 0):

This comes very close:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:.6 green:.65 blue:.69 alpha:.9]
```

You'd need to design a custom view to emulate the gradient and the bottom border.